# How to set up an entry point for the jar artifact created through Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, testng

I am working on automatin testing framework and for that I am using testNG, Java , Jenkins.

I created a jar artifact using Jenkins. Through Jenkins I am sending parameters to pom.xml to tell pom.xml to which TestNG.xml file to execute. TestNG.xml contains lists of tests.

So once jenkins build is successful I will take that jar and I want to execute it every time any changes are deployed on the site.
Any idea how can I execute this jar by setting up an entry point? This might be a dumb question but I am asking this since I am new to Java, Jenkins stuff.

I have following values in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>.\\testNG-xml\\regression\\MyTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <env1>${env1}</env1>
                        <env2>${env2}</env2>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Could you clarify? What do you want? What do you have? Please go into the details.

Comment: I executed a Jenkin's job (it had some smoke tests) - which created a artifact for me. I got jar from this artifact and I want  to run this jar every time something gets deployed to the site. That means every time after deployment I wan to execute smoke tests to make sure nothing is broken.

Answer (score 1):

So what I understood from your question is that you have a project already create in Jenkins that builds your test code.Test Code is in a separate repository from the Application under test.You now need to execute these tests whenever the application under test has a commit.

There is an option of executing a post script in Jenkins.The steps you would need to follow are as follows:
1) Create a copy of the project that builds your test code.
2) Replace the repository URL with the URL of application Under test repository.
3) Set the repository polling interval to 15 min.
4) Call your TestCase JAR with the required parameters using a post build action feature in Jenkins.

An important point to note here is that any test reports generated by this external test suite will have to be backed up by you.

So the flow will be as follows:
Jenkins will poll your dev branch at 15 min, If a checkin is found it will create the build.If the checkin is not a build breaking checkin, and the build succeeds, the post build action will run which essentially runs your tests.

Comment: Thank you Surabhi. Actually Jenkins will create a build for our automation coding tests (output will be jar file). Now I want to execute this jar file every time developer commits their changes (I mean application under test changes).

Comment: Thank you Surabhi. I will follow the approach you mentioned. So in post build action I will execute my Jar but when I execute Jar do you have any idea how can I pass parameters and setup entry point for this Jar  (test automation is a maven project)

Comment: Post build action is actually a command to execute .So just write something like mvn -f pathtoPom -D someParam=value -D otherParam=Value

Comment: Thank you Surabh for helping me out. I have added my pom.xml code in the question above. 1. After jenkins creates artifact I will use this jar file and 2. Pass parameters to this jar file to execute it using command- mvn -f pathtoPom -Denv1=abc -Denv2=xyz. Right?

Comment: Just correct the path to testNG xml in your POM to something like this src/test/resources/testng1.xml instead of .\\testNG-xml\\regression\\MyTest.xml and it should work.